# How To Ignore Error In Powershell Script (ErrorAction: SilentlyContinue not suppressing error)

Tags: powershell

I have a Powershell script that lists all the users/groups in the local administrators group for all computers in a designated OU in Active Directory.

The script works perfectly locally (if I run it against the local machine only) but when I run it against remote machines, it technically works but it throws a consistent error that I don't know how to filter out.

Here is the script (NOTE: must be running from ActiveDirectory PS console to use Get-ADComputer):

```
Get-ADComputer -SearchBase 'OU=ou01,dc=domain,dc=local' -Filter 'ObjectClass -eq "Computer"' `
    | ForEach-Object { 
        Get-WmiObject win32_groupuser -cn $_.name -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue `
            | Where-Object { $_.groupcomponent -match 'administrators' } `
            | ForEach-Object -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue {[wmi]$_.partcomponent } `
            | Select-Object __SERVER,Caption 
     } | Format-Table -Property * -AutoSize
```

Here are the results (correct result is in first line, error below that):

```
__SERVER          Caption
--------          -------
workstation_name  workstation_name\Administrator
Cannot convert value "\\workstation_name\root\cimv2:Win32_Group.Domain="DOMAIN",Name="Domain Admins"" to type "System.Management.ManagementObject". Error: "Not found "
At line:1 char:306
+ Get-ADComputer -SearchBase 'OU=ou01,dc=domain,dc=local' -Filter 'ObjectClass -eq "Computer"' | ForEach-Object { Get-WmiObject win32_groupuser -cn $_.name -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object { $_.groupcomponent -match 'administrators' } | ForEach-Object -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue {[wmi]$_. <<<< partcomponent } | Select-Object __SERVER,Caption } | Format-Table -Property * -AutoSize
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException
```

I have unsuccessfully tried to use -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue, is there another way to suppress this message? Not sure what I am missing.

Comment: This answer may be of use in your situation https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/4m8rzg/is_it_possible/d3tiyn8

Comment: @AnthonyStringer I tried the link you provided (thanks!) and it did get me further down the road, but getting that object provided by the $Matches into a CSV/table was not happening easily so I had to bail on finishing this the way I hoped (deadline). I ended up removing everything after the ForEach-Object and just exporting out the 2 fields I needed and did a little Excel cleanup. Thanks again for the help!